# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (15,15) into shape (15)

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

```
import numpy 
HL1_neurons = 15
input_HL1_weights = numpy.random.uniform(low=-0.1, high=0.1,size=(15, HL1_neurons))
output_neurons = 1
HL2_output_weights = numpy.random.uniform(low=-0.1, high=0.1,size=(HL1_neurons, 1))
weights = numpy.array([input_HL1_weights,HL2_output_weights])
```

while execting the code HL1_neurons is accepting any number other than 15

if it is 15 it is showing following error please help me in this regard

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-97fe596c0407> in <module>
      4 output_neurons = 1
      5 HL2_output_weights = numpy.random.uniform(low=-0.1, high=0.1,size=(HL1_neurons, 1))
----> 6 weights = numpy.array([input_HL1_weights.astype(object),HL2_output_weights.astype(object)])

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (15,15) into shape (15)
```

Comment: What do you think `numpy.array([input_HL1_weights,HL2_output_weights])` does?

Answer (score 0):

`input_HL1_weights` is (15,15) shape.  `HL2_output_weights` is (15,1).

Trying to make an object dtype array from these two, results in this kind of error.  If their shapes differed in the first dimensions (e.g. their transposes), the result would be a (2,) object dtype array.  If the shapes matched the shape would be (2,n,m).  This a known problem with using `np.array(...)` to create an object dtype array.

What exactly do you want to produce?

A more reliable way to produce a (2,) object array is:

```
weights = np.empty(2, object)
weights[0] = input_HL1_weights
weights[1] = HL2_output_weights
```

This removes the ambiguity about what to do if the shapes match, or match partially.